# preg_replace array php simple html dom parser

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace a repetitive word of an array, so I do this:

```
$thisarray = preg_replace ("/HELLO/"), "BYE", $thisarray);

echo $thisarray[0];
```

That works perfect... the problem comes when I use a PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER instruction "plaintext"

```
$thisarray = preg_replace ("/HELLO/"), "BYE", $thisarray);

echo $thisarray[0]->plaintext;
```

It says: **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in**

Comment: var_dump($thisarray) and find out if plaintext exists

Answer (score 2):

`$thisarray` is either an array of strings or an array of simple_html_dom instances.  *Pick one*.

If it's the former, they won't even be objects, and thus can't have a `plaintext` property.

And if it's the latter, be careful passing it to a function that expects strings.  A function that wants strings will either choke on objects or stringify them as needed.  Even assuming a `simple_html_dom` knows how to convert itself to a string, `preg_replace` will *return* a string (or an array of strings) as well.  That means once `preg_replace` does its thing and you replace `$thisarray` with the return value, no matter what it was before, *now you have an array of strings*.  See above.

Comment: Not to mention this code could never possibly run anyway, given the syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, there's that too.  But i assume that was just a typo, given that the code ran far enough to throw an error about non-object properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, preg_replace is not a function that is performant if you just want to replace a world instead of a pattern. For your case, `str_replace` is better.

Then, you just misuse $thisarray variable. Before your function, it is an object, after, it is no longer an object as preg_replace returns a string OR an array.

so, you can have sort of cleaner code with that :

```
$textToReplace = array('/HELLO/','other world to replace');
replacementText = array('BYE','other replacemnt text');
$cleanText = str_replace($textToReplace,$replacementText,$thisarray[0]->plaintext);
echo $cleanText;
```